# Watch a folder on another server for changes

Tags: powershell

I need to watch a folder on another server so when a new file appears in that folder it is copied to another folder.

But I don't know how to do this with credentials. My script give-me errors when I try to watch the folder.

```
 $folder = '10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Tratar'
$filter = '*.xls*'   
$folder2 = Get-Date -UFormat "%m-%Y"
$destination = '\\10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\' + $folder2 
$destination2 = 'D:\Import_Jbrandao\Click'

Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "Folder With Whatch:"  $folder
Write-Host "Folder Destination:"  $destination
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------"

$ComputerName = "10.162.106.30" 
$UserName = "UserName"
$Password = "********"
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName , $SecurePassword 
$Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential

Write-Host "** Whatch Folder **"
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true             
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
get-event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated

#Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$nameFile = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
Write-Host "** Watch has something **"
Write-Host "Year:" $nameFile.Substring(40,4)
Write-Host "Month:" $nameFile.Substring(45,2)
Write-Host "Day:" $nameFile.Substring(48,2)

 $name = "BYSIDE_" + $nameFile.Substring(40,4) + '_' + $nameFile.Substring(45,2)  + '_' + $nameFile.Substring(48,6)
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
Rename-Item -Path $path -NewName $name 
Write-Host "** Name file was changed **" 
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
 Write-Host "Try move from " $path\$namefile " To " $destination\$name
 Move-Item $folder\$name -Destination $destination\$name -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
 Write-Host "Start Program Import C2C"

 Write-Host "Stop if have 'ImportIndicadores.exe' running"
 Get-Process ImportIndicadores | Stop-Process
 # -NoLogo -NonInteractive -File
 Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
 Write-Host "Start 'ImportIndicadores.exe'"
 Start-Process -FilePath "C:\APPS_Manual\IF Don't Work (SOS)\C2C_Telefonia.appref-ms"
 Write-Host "Wait 20 Seconds"
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
Write-Host "Copy From " $destination\$name " To " $destination2\$name
Copy-Item $destination\$name -Destination $destination2\$name -Force -Verbose
}
```

Errors:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The directory name 10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Tratar 
>   is invalid." At C:\PowerShell\Click\Click2Call.ps1:23 char:18
>   + $fsw = New-Object <<<<  IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>
> Get-Event : Event with source identifier 'FileCreated' does not exist.
>   At C:\PowerShell\Click\Click2Call.ps1:27 char:10
>   + get-event <<<<  -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Event], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : INVALID_SOURCE_IDENTIFIER,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventCommand
>
> Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject'
>   because it is null. At C:\PowerShell\Click\Click2Call.ps1:30 char:34
>   + $onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent <<<<  $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Register-ObjectEvent], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObjectEventCommand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitor folder on remote PC for changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448361/monitor-folder-on-remote-pc-for-changed-files)

Comment: My problem is the credentials, i think i can't get files because miss the credentials.

Comment: Well if this is your actual code then this '10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Tratar' would not be a valid path. You are missing a \\ at the beginning.

Comment: It's the same  - 

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The directory name \\10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Trat
ar is invalid."
At C:\PowerShell\Click\Click2Call.ps1:23 char:18
+ $fsw = New-Object <<<<  IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: This is the folder that the error is saying is bad: "\\10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Trat ar". This is the folder that you say you are using: "\\10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Tratar". I believe the computer. ***What are you actually running in your code?***

Comment: The path exists, and if i enter with my credentials in mapped drive, the script run fine, but i want run the script without login on windows mapped drive. I'm runnig the script above

Comment: Which path exists? The one that you have in your post or the one in the error? Because they are not the same.

Comment: The path that exists on the server 10.162.106.30 is: D: \ IPE \ CRMA \ To Tratar
The space that appears in the error(Por Trat ar) is just log, as it does not have space to write the entire path in the line does a break in the log

Comment: Is the script running with your user account?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were missing the `\\` before the IP address.

```
$folder = '\\10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Tratar'
```

Comment: It's the same - New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The directory name \\10.162.106.30\d$\IPE\CRMA\Por Trat ar is invalid." At C:\PowerShell\Click\Click2Call.ps1:23 char:18 + $fsw = New-Object <<<< IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand –